# CSS not applied on install, but loaded properly

Tags: theming, 8

I have installed Drupal 8, but the default CSS is not applied (see http://ec2-54-187-215-79.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/user/1 for example).

[image]

Chrome's 'inspect' functionality reveals that the CSS is loaded properly from http://ec2-54-187-215-79.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/sites/default/files/css/css_4w6DyMZOD_Fu1oxqpACBFcOPDgVYtgOuayu9S6-8btc.css?0

What is causing this issue? How can I solve it?

Comment: It seems to be like that is the minimum CSS that is been load from Stark. I could be wrong. Could you provide an example of the libraries definition  and if you are loading it from a Theme or a Module ?

Comment: I have just performed the installation, so this is the delivered CSS. What do you mean by library definition? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you installed it, for Installation Profile, did you select Standard? or did you select Minimal?

[image]

It seems like you selected Minimal, which I highly do not recommend, Standard is the way to go. Delete all the tables in your DataBase and go to http://ec2-54-187-215-79.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/install.php and install again.

Comment: I think I selected minimal. I'll try your recommendation.